# Display List data from a separate Sharepoint 2010 instance?

Tags: 2010, list-view

We have two completely separate instances of SharePoint 2010 from the merging of two companies.  We have a list on one SharePoint instance that we would like to display on a page from the other SharePoint instance.  Is this possible? I've seen a possible jQuery solution and maybe using DataView web part but these were between lists on the same farm.  Would this be possible? Thanks!

Comment: Are they using separate AD?

Comment: for a very simple solution, couldn't you just use a page viewer web part on one of the two SharePoint instances that displays a page from the other instance? Have you got some other more restrictive requirements (different AD like Erin said, need for more complex interraction and such)?

Comment: No, we are on separate ADs for now with plans to be on one AD in a few months. Also, the preference was to not use an iframe if we can avoid it.